# I have a Belkin router, can I see the prototype of it?

Tags: wifi, router

Hello guys I have a router (Belkin) so I wonder how can I see the functionality (source code) of the router? or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Belin driver source code from here:

http://www.belkin.com/support/opensource/

Not all of their products have open source drivers. If the one you're looking for isn't here, then the answer is no, you can't have it.